# Intel SGX Service Provider

Tags: intel, sgx

I want to implement in my project the Intel SGX remote attestation mecanisme.
this mecanisme requires the **Service Provider** and a IAS server.
My problem is: what is exactly a **Service Provider**, is it an ordinary server in which we install an API or something else.
How to configure this SP in order to implement remote attestation mecanisme.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have in mind [Intel's RA example](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/code-sample/software-guard-extensions-remote-attestation-end-to-end-example.html):

[image: remote attestation scheme]
<sub>(source: [intel.com](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/13/b8/Guard-Extensions-Remote-Attestation-End-to-End-Example-fig2.png))</sub>

There are three different actors involved:

- **Client Application**, who is a host to the enclave
- **Service Provider**, who performs remote attestation on Client's behalf
- **Attestation Service** (IAS, Intel Attestation Service), who is a trusted third party tasked with verifying the enclave

This example implements remote attestation in a client-server architecture where the Client Application acts as a client and the Service Provider acts as a server. So yes, the Service Provider could be an ordinary server that provides Client Application with some API.

This is a useful pattern if you intend to perform RA across many applications - but it's not required. You can implement RA algorithm in Client Application instead and talk to the Attestation Service directly.